# AnimationTimer() for Collision Detection

Tags: javafx, collision

I have two game objects that are rectangles, a Player and an Enemy. I want the player to jump on the Y axis and the Enemy to slide along the X axis. When the Player's X,Y position match the Enemy's it should kill the Player. So far, I can't get the AnimationTimer() to check every frame for the constant X position and Y position. It only checks when the application first starts and keeps those values.

How do I get it to check every frame for the X position and Y position of the two rectangles?

```
AnimationTimer animator = new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long arg0) {
            //update

            double playX = player.getX(), enemX = enemy.getX();
            double playY = player.getY(), enemY = enemy.getY();
            System.out.println("Player's X: "+ playX + "\n" + "Enemy's X: " + enemX);
            System.out.println("Player's Y: "+ playY);

            if (playX == enemX && playY == enemY){
                System.out.println("Player has Collided with Enemy");
            }

        }//handle
    };
    animator.start();//animation
```

Comment: What type of `Object` is enemy?

Comment: This is not perfect but you can get some ideas from [here](https://github.com/sedj601/DiverFx/tree/Diver_latest/src/diverapp)

Comment: @Sedrick the enemy is a rectangle, as well as the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(player, enemy);

if(intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1)
{
    System.out.println("Player has Collided with Enemy");
}
```

Comment: wow, I don't even know what to say. I've been trying to get this to work since about Wednesday. Thank you so much.

Comment: If the answer help, accept it as correct.